# How to change image canvas size in Kivy

Tags: python, image, canvas, kivy, size

I make digital car dashboard on Raspberry Pi with python Kivy and I need to show RPM in real time.
I have 2 images, scale7000.png and rpmBar.png

[image]
[image]

I need to show part of the rpmBar.png, as example 50%
[image]

I'm create a image:

```
self.rpmBar = Image(source='rpmBar.png', size_hint=(None,None), height=154, width=800, pos=(0,240))
self.add_widget(self.rpmBar)
```

How to set new canvas size? like this pseudo code:

```
self.rpmBar.canvas_width = 50%
```

Comment: Try putting the `rpmBar.png` inside a `StencilView`. Then to adjust the rpms,  you adjust the `StencilView`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson you should promote your comment to an Answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

John Anderson thanks! StencilView is the right way

```
self.rpmBar = StencilView(size_hint=(None,None), size=(800,154),pos=(0,240))
self.rpmBarImage = Image(source='rpmBar.png', size=(800,154), pos=(0,240))
self.rpmBar.add_widget(self.rpmBarImage)
self.add_widget(self.rpmBar)

self.rpmBar.width = 500
```

Comment: Hi. Your project is very interesting. Would it be possible to share your source-code somewhere? Thank you.

Comment: There is project "Digital cockpit on Raspberry Pi" https://github.com/aivs/blackCockpit